# What does .Net do when you declare an object without an instance?

Tags: c#, .net, object, memory-management

I wonder to know how the **.Net Framework** handles the *declared but not instantiated object* situation.

For example i declare an object like

```
DropDownList ddl;
```

and do nothing about it. I know that i should do something with this variable and get a warning about it, but what i don't know is the where it will be stored.

Is there a lookup table that stores the data of all declared variables? Or is there a virtual reference for every declaration?

Edit : I just wanted to know how the memory allocated for this object declaration.

Edit2 : Whether it's a local variable or not, i'm just talking about the memory allocation structure. I wonder to know where this references stored.

Comment: Are you talking about a *variable* (as inside a method) or a *field* (as inside a class)?

Comment: I tried to mean both of them.

Comment: You don't declare objects. You declare variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `ddl` is a field, then the value of `ddl` will be `null`, as it is a reference type.

Any attempt to call a member on it will result in a [`NullReferenceException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.nullreferenceexception.aspx).

If it is a local variable it will simply be unassigned.

Value types will get the `default(T)` of their type.

The compiler itself may remove the call completely, depending on where it was declared, but this is an implementation detail.

Comment: Don't forget value types. Wouldn't it be more like `default(T)`?

Comment: It certainly won't be removed if it's a field in a class.

Comment: @asawyer - `DropDownList` is not a value type ;)

Comment: @Oded That's just the example, the question is about `the declared but not instantiated object situation` and I don't think he is taking ref/val semantics into account. :)

Comment: If it's a field it can't be removed. If it's a local variable it's unassigned, not null.

Comment: Isn't this answer wrong? Any attempt to *touch* the variable (even reference-compare it to something) will result in a compiler error so this won't even make it to runtime (never mind an exception).

Comment: @Jon - A field will compile just fine.

Comment: @Oded: Sure, but there's a comment saying "I 'd like to know both ways". So not wrong (that was too harsh) -- but maybe needs some clarification? I see the "and a field", but it's not too prominent.

Comment: @Oded: Better. Still room for improvement IMHO but I 'm not going to nitpick. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about a local variable then the compiler can simply optimize it out of existence since noone can be using it (if you attempted to use it without initializing the compiler would have protested with an error). In fact the .NET 4 compiler did this for me when I tested just moments ago.

If you are talking about a field in a class then it is initialized with the [default value for its type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/83fhsxwc.aspx) as part of the object construction.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it sounds like you're talking about a local variable. When you declare a local variable *in usual implementations and without any optimizations*, then space is reserved for it on the stack (most probably), with a `null` reference as its value.

You could look into the `StackFrame` class if you want to inspect further (I've never used it).

Answer (score 1):

The variable is stored in your assembly. It will always have it's default value null.

In release mode (compiler is set to optimize) it's optimized and it is not stored anywhere.

If you want to know more about IL and how the compiler works, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) has a good article to start.

Answer (score 1):

All variables are stored into a class or method. Variables declared into a class can be listed using **.NET Reflection** :

```
class Class1 { private int i; public string s; }
typeof(Class1).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance); // returns all instance fields
typeof(Class1).GetFields(); // returns all instance public fields
typeof(Class1).GetProperties(); // returns all instance public properties
```

**Variables declared into a method cannot be inspected with .NET Reflection mechanisms.**